# How to do time running using Java

Tags: java

I have `start_time` and `end_Time`, so I tried to print those `interval_times` (time format 24).

How do I do it?

```
int start = Integer.parseInt("10:24:49");
int end = Integer.parseInt("11:24:49");

for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
{
    System.out.println("result  i ="+ i);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Java 8, the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package has been the optimal way to do all date/time related things.

It takes some getting used to, e.g. when it comes to timezones, but it's absolutely worth the effort!

Here's the code for your seconds printer:

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public static void main(final String[] args) {

    // Just so you know it in the future. Not needed in this example.
    final DateTimeFormatter dtfDateTime = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);

    final DateTimeFormatter dtfTime = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);

    final LocalTime ltStart = LocalTime.of(10, 24, 49);
    final LocalTime ltEnd = ltStart.plusHours(1);

    // If you want to use String parsing to get your instance:
    final LocalTime ltStartViaParsing = LocalTime.from(dtfTime.parse("10:24:49"));

    LocalTime i = ltStart;
    while (i.isBefore(ltEnd)) {

        System.out.println("result i = " + dtfTime.format(i));
        i = i.plusSeconds(1);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
result i = 10:24:49
result i = 10:24:50
result i = 10:24:51
...
result i = 11:24:46
result i = 11:24:47
result i = 11:24:48
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to run the loop for particular duration of time.

In case you want to run the loop for fixed duration like for 5 minutes, with a 5 second interval, you can do it   like this:

```
try {
     // This loop will run for 5 minutes for every 5 second delay
     for(int i=0;i<60;i++) {
       System.out.println(new Date());
        Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);
    }
}
catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Before using, see comments below.**

If you are intending to print every hour between two given times, then you are totally on the wrong path.

```
Integer.parseInt
```

It is intended to get a String number and converts it to Java Integer.

Try to use SimpleDateFormat and Date and Calendar

```
String startTime = "10:24:49";
String endTime = "11:24:49";
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(sdf.parse(startTime));
int start = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

calendar.setTime(sdf.parse(endTime));
int end = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

Comment: Where possible, `java.time` should be used instead of older solutions like `java.util.calendar`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/legacy.html

Comment: Thanks for mentioning. I agree

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
DateTime startTime, endTime;
Period p = new Period(startTime, endTime);
int hours = p.getHours();
int minutes = p.getMinutes();
```

And also you can use `Java.util.Timer` to schedule a thread to be executed at a certain time in the future.